# sync data from MySQL/SQL to server on interval basis

Tags: mysql, sql-server, etl, data-synchronization

I want to sync Mysql/SQL data from my clients to my SQL server on interval bases. Right now I am doing it by my own application. Can anyone suggest me any faster way?

which way is best in my scenario?

Comment: There are a few solutions based on Data replication and ETL that you look into. for more complex and fine-grained replication you can look into a technology called CDC which is used in a production environment. the best offering of CDC is this can be used with heterogeneous databases.